# IIS Features Installation for ASP.net Development

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am planning on installing IIS for local ASP.net deployments for testing purposes only. I do not want to enable unnecessary features; which features should I install/enable for development purposes?

Comment: What version of IIS? What OS? Standalone machine or on your dev PC?

Comment: Have you looked at IIS Express?  If your concerns are security related, by default, it only accepts connections from localhost, and it doesn't require you to run Visual Studio as admin.  If you happen to be working with VS 2010/SP1, then it integrates with visual studio as well.

Comment: I'm not sure which version of IIS, this is on a Windows 7 Professional development machine. I am installing IIS through "turn windows features on or off". I will look into the express version, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use other web service which is light weight.. like Ultra..

Comment: use UltiDev Cassini 2.0 if possible its nice and easy to use